# import data using data loader - How to use it secured?

Tags: data-loader

We opt to use data loader to load the accounts, opportunites, leads etc in live. So the question is how to load it secured with some sort of encryption in live as these are critical data and we are using a cloud based apps?

Comment: So your concern about the Salesforce security (we are using a cloud based apps?) or data loader connection to Salesforce or encrypting your data ?

Comment: Data loader connecting to salesforce and how secure would it be? Do we need to encrypt business critical indo prior upload?